# How to mark email follow up flag complete in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I've just upgraded to Office 365 and have Outlook 2013 with that. Previously, the follow up 'flags' had multiple flag options, as well as the capability to set reminders with them and a 'check mark' option to mark an email complete.

My brain is now trained to manage my inbox this way and I cannot figure out how to find more than just one red flag option in the current version, there is no 'mark complete' option.

What do I do?!

Comment: Consumer or Business?

Answer (score 3):

I tested this and got all the screenshots from an installation of Office
Professional 2013 but I expect that it should work the same across all versions of Office 2013.

The first way to do what you asked would be to right click on the e-mail in question and go down to `Follow Up`. In here are all the options that you requested, including `Mark Complete`, all of the different quick flags and access to the `Add Reminder...` function.

[image: Structure of right click menu on E-mails in Outlook 2013]

Other options include using the flag icon on the right hand side of the e-mail in the list (this won't be visible until you hover over the e-mail itself), coloured red in the image below. Clicking it once will enable a flag for today and clicking it a second time will mark it as complete. Right clicking on the flag itself also provides a faster route to all of the `Follow Up` settings.

[image: An e-mail in Outlook 2013 with the flag symbol highlighted]

You can also do all of this from the Ribbon as well, either from the main window or from inside an e-mail. If you have not opened the e-mail, make sure it is highlighted in the list of e-mails and ensure that you are on the `HOME` tab (in the top left of the window). Look for the `Tags` section, in which you will find a `Follow Up` entry which works the same as mentioned before.

If you've opened the e-mail, make sure that you're on the `MESSAGE` tab in the top left, and then find the section called `Tags`. Again, `Follow Up` is here and has access to all of the settings you needed.

[image: The "Tags" section in the Ribbon in Outlook 2013]

After looking into this issue a bit more, it seems that [the `Follow Up` options will only work for users on a POP or hosted Exchange account](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/followup-does-not-give-any-options/2784b02c-63b1-4aa8-b970-812e629942f2). If the account that you're working with isn't one of these, the best workaround is to select the message that you want to add the flag to and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (which should work irrespective of account type). This will bring up a window in which you can create a flag, specifying the start and end dates as well as being able to set a reminder. Unfortunately, this option doesn't allow for access to the `Mark Complete` option.

[image: Custom Flag Menu in Outlook 2013]

For those who are interested, the reason that the `Follow Up` options are so restricted (at least for IMAP accounts) seems to be because [they can't be synced back to the server](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-categories-flags-and-imap-accounts/).

Comment: Matt, Thanks so much for trying to help, but I dont have all the options you mentioned above. I'm trying to figure out how to enable them.  In the first option you suggested, when I get to 'follow up' there is only one red flag, not all the different flags and the add reminder and mark complete.  And I even figured out how to add these items to the ribbon at the top, but they aren't activated/enabled.  you can see them, but they aren't 'clickable'.  Any suggestions on how to do this? THANKS!!!

Comment: @CourtneyDuell I've edited the question and added a new section that should hopefully answer your question a bit better.